# Can't make MakeFile c++ with -lcrypto

Tags: c++, makefile

Good day. I need to write makefile for my program. I only have ukol2.cpp. When i compile in terminal i write:

`g++ -Wall ukol2.cpp -lcrypto -o prog; ./prog d`

Also i have template:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g
LDFLAGS = -lcrypto

all: hash stream
run:
    #run your tests here...
hash: hash.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)
stream: stream.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Can you help to write my own makefile with same C and LD flags?